# Stack Pointer Offsets: Calling Functions while passing arguments to stack

Tags: assembly, avr

Good evening, I am attempting to call a basic function while grabbing arguments that I have passed into the SP. When I call the function, the stack pointer changes its value and everything gets crazy. Every example I see online does not talk about the Stack Pointer changing when a function is called. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
;SP is initialized, SP = $21FF
             ;Pushing values to stack using r16
ldi R16, $44 ;wordH
push r16     ;SP = $21FE
ldi R16, $42 ;wordL
push r16     ;SP = $21FD
ldi R16, $02 ;byte
push r16     ;SP = $21FC

rcall dostuff
nop
done: rjmp done

;------Function------; (Function gutted for StackExchange)

dostuff:         ;Call multiply, SP = $21F9
    pop r17       ;Stuff gets wonky here
    pop r18 
    pop r19
loop:
    dec r17
    breq return
    rjmp loop
return:
    ret
```

For some reason the SP changed from $21FC to $21F9 when I call the function. Am I passing arguments to the stack incorrectly? Or does the stack pointer change to preserve information? If so how should I go about passing arguments to the stack?

Comment: The stack pointer changes because `rcall` itself places the return address there. You don't normally pop arguments in functions, you just access them and leave the removal to the caller who put them there in the first place. If you need to interoperate with other code, be sure to consult the calling convention documentation.

Comment: Would you suggest storing $21FC in a pointer variable and using that to load indirectly with post increment?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. [avr-gcc uses the Y register for that](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Frame_Layout).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to accomplish what I set out to do. Instead of popping, used `in YH, SPH`, and `in YL, SPL`. To load those values into registers I used `ldd: load with displacement`, since `ld` does not have pre-increment

Comment: An alternative to passing arguments on the stack would be to pass them in registers. You can also see how GCC does that in link Jester provided above.